# How to set data to listview using Retrofit?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

Firstly This is code. But this is not real code.

API_Interface.java

```
public interface API_Interface{
    @GET("/api/foo")
    Call<Foo> foo_API();
}
```

foo.java

```
public class foo{
    @SerializedName("foo")
    @Expose
    private String foo;

    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    String buzz;
    Retrofit foo_retro;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        ArrayList<foo> fooList = new ArrayList<foo>();
        FooAdapter fooAdapter = new FooAdapter(this, 0, fooList);
        listView.setAdapter(fooAdapter);

        ...

        foo_retro = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://api.foo.com")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();  

        API_Interface foo_service = foo_retro.create(API_Interface.class)

        Call<foo> foo_call=foo_service.foo_API();
        foo_call.enqueue(new Callback<foo>() {             
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<foo> call, Response<foo> response) {
                buzz = response.body().getFoo();
                System.out.println(buzz);
            } 

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<zaifExchange> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        });
        fooList.add(new foo(buzz));
        System.out.println(buzz);
    }
}
```

When I run this code, I can get and print `buzz` (like "Apple") in the `onResponse` method. 
However, I can't set data to `listview` (`buzz` is null).
I know the reason is that `enqueue` is asynchronous, so the terminal shows:

```
I/System.out: null
I/System.out: Apple
```

So what should I do?
Thanks.

Comment: What is your API response ?

Comment: onResponse set responce data to your arraylist   "fooList "  and than set to adapter

Answer (score 3):

Add response into `fooList` inside `onResponse` otherwise you are adding `null` values as

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<foo> call, Response<foo> response) {
    buzz = response.body().getFoo();
    fooList.add(new foo(buzz));
    System.out.println(buzz);
    fooAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   // ^^^^ notify changes to display data 
   // you might want to declare references outside oncreate to avoid local variables
}
```

remove

```
fooList.add(new foo(buzz));
System.out.println(buzz);
```

(outside `enqueue`)because before response `buzz` will be `null`

Comment: thanks your anwer!! I could display data! (notifyDataSetChanged() was needed)

Comment: @NooNoo i am glad that it helped, happy coding

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, your problem is twofold:

1. Consider adding in a delay before you print in the `onCreate()` method, itself. Better yet, verify that `buzz` has actually been set before continuing.
2. Because `enqueue()` is asynchronous, no matter happens, `buzz` will likely not be seen by the parent thread that does the printing. Instead, consider wrapping the `buzz` field using the [`AtomicReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) class. That way, regardless of the thread, the most up-to-date value of `buzz` will be seen by any thread.

Comment: `Consider adding in a delay` bad idea , what if response comes early and late than the added delay and 2 point not needed at all, will only add unwanted nonworking complexity

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh thats a fair point, and why I stated at the end "Better yet, verify that buzz has actually been set before continuing."

Comment: and you are right about this though the suggested solutions will only bring more code & unexpected complexity in this case buddy

Comment: Perhaps. I'm just looking at the problem from a general concurrency problem point of view. I don't know much about listview, but these types of practices that I've listed have served me well in the past when dealing with concurrency issues, which is definitely something that I'm seeing here.

Comment: yup it's similar to java though i would say it's more of a `asynchronous` issue because retrofit (network calls library) will trigger a thread on background and give the response on UI thread